# Recover data from lkdkjya file format

Tags: php, virus

Some of my video and php file has been converted into .lkdkjya file format but the antivirus do not detect them as virus. Can someone help me to retrieve them back without formatting especially php files?

Comment: There's no `.lkdkjya` file format, so we don't know what kind of modification were made by this virus

Comment: Is it possible to format the whole thing and recover the original file format?

Comment: I found the solution. I used BDG and Crab Decrypt Tools to recover back infected files. Thanks anyway @barbsan for the response